# ASP.Net Web API Authentication using Authorize attribute and WorldDomination plugin

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm reasonably new to web development so please forgive me if my terminology is off a bit.

I've created an ASP.Net Web API, and for certain methods on the API I'm needing a way to tell if a user is authenticated in order to make such a call.  For example, on certain methods I need to tell the user id of the user who is making the call.

I've done some reading about the AllowAnonymous and Authorize attributes ( System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute and System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymousAttribute).  From the reading that I have done, for a REST api, it really should use the System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute, not the Mvc one (as mentioned here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#auth3).  I've got the controller and methods with appropriate attributes so that the controller is marked with an [Authorize] attribute and any publicly available methods are marked with [AllowAnonymous].  I can verify this works by calling a publicly available method and it works, and calling an [Authorize] method and I get a 401 response.

I've currently got things hooked up to the WorldDomination package to authenticate with third parties (https://github.com/PureKrome/WorldDomination.Web.Authentication).  This seems to be about the simplest way of authenticating with Twitter, Facebook, Google, etc.  How this works is the user of the web site (which is using the Web API) clicks on the login link (via Twitter, Google, Facebook, etc.).  They are then taken to a usual login page that looks something like this (in this example, it is using Twitter):

[image: Usual login page]

If the user allows access, there is a method that gets called on the server which has access to the HttpContextBase, as well as the user data returned by the 3rd party (including things like the provider name, access token, username, user id, etc.).  Likewise, if the user cancels, or doesn't allow permission, there's a similar function that gets called.  Its at this point in the success function that I'm associating the 3rd party user with my own internal user id, which I then later on need to use on various other API calls (e.g.: creating objects requires a user id to know who created it).

It's at this point that I'm a bit stuck.  From what I understand, in order to make an authenticated call to the web API, I need to pass it a username:password, encoded as a 64 bit string in the request header.  The thing is, I'm not storing a username/password (nor do I want to store passwords!).

What exactly am I supposed to use for my "username:password", and how do I store it on the client so that it can be used for subsequent calls?  Could I use my own internal user id as the username and the access token (granted from the third party) as the password, or should the password be some randomly generated Guid that gets created each time the user logs in via the 3rd party?  The site will eventually be running over Https with a certificate.  Ideally, I'd like to avoid the user having to log in every time they visit the site.

I suppose in the mean time, I could use standard forms authentication, which uses a client side cookie to store details, but I am eventually going to need to know how to do authentication without the client side cookie, as I'm trying to keep the API accessible to multiple platforms (including apps on mobile devices).  From my limited understanding, some of these platforms don't necessarily use cookies, and would require things to be authenticated using the standard http authentication details that are included on each call.